# How to obtain UIImage from UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm struggling to figure out how I can obtain an image from a UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL (I know that I can obtain it directly from `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` however, I have reasons for wanting not to).  Here's what I have

```
/* 
 *   Responds when an image is selected (from browsing)
 */
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{        
        UIImage *image = [self obtainImageAtURLPath:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
        if(!image) return;
        //...more code here
}
- (UIImage *) obtainImageAtURLPath:(NSURL *) urlPath
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[urlPath path]];
    return image;
}
```

However, when I do this, I always get `nil` instead of my image.  The urlPath exists; however,  it doesn't want to be converted to a UIImage.  Help please.

If I print out `NSLog(@"%@", urlPath)` I get `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=53784678-BD17-4EE4-9A96-601B81012AFE&ext=JPG`

If I print out `NSLog(@"%@", [urlPath path])` I get `/asset.JPG`.

Comment: What kind of image is it? Show the URL

Comment: It's an image that was taken using the iPad camera. I'll post the actual path in just a sec

Comment: @Dustin see actual path in edit above. Thanks

Comment: That's why; depending on the iOS you're running apple won't just let you access camera info. Try using a different URL to something you have access to and see if it works.

Comment: Try using the `AssetsLibrary` framework http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/how-to-display-thumbnail-images-in-iphone-table-view/

Comment: Also, although this probably won't give you access to the image, try NSLog on `[urlPath absoluteString]` instead of just `path`

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question here:[name of the picked image xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13512415/1548523). You should use `ALAssetsLibrary` to load that image asset using that kind of `urlPath`.