# name of the picked image xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get the name of the image picked from the library or newly clicked in -

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I am using this code:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        NSLog(@"imagekbgfg=====>%@",image);
        [self.imageView setImage:image];

        imgName = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        del.mainImgName = imgName;
        del.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        del.imageApp = image;
    }

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
       image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the code bellow you will get path like:`assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=79450962-C0FD-484C-808B-83E045F40972&ext=JPG` when your picking image from photo album. This path is valid. It contains the asset ID and asset type.

```
// Firstly get the picked image's file URL.
NSURL *imageFileURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

// Then get the file name.
NSString *imageName = [imageFileURL lastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"image name is %@", imageName);
```

If you want to get image user picked again using the path you get using `UIImagePickerController`.(Here maybe you want to save the path so that you can read that image back without asking user to pick that image again) You will need the `ALAssetsLibrary` otherwise you don't need it.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
__block UIImage *returnValue = nil;
[library assetForURL:imageFileURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    returnValue = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Why will you ask this question? You have used `UIImagePickerController`. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I mean has it something to do with ALAssetsLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol. The string **UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL** contains an URL of your file. You could use it to construct the filename from it.

Other than that there seems to be no built-in way to get the file name from an UIImage or UIImageView object.

Reference:
[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242935/how-to-obtain-the-original-file-name-of-the-image-picked-by-uiimagepickercontrol)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file name using below code:

```
NSURL *assetURL = [imageDic objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

 __block NSString *originalFileName = nil;

 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
 [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
             originalFileName = [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename];
}
```

originalFileName give the original file name of resource.