# I want to convert AlAsset object to nsstring to store it in database

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am trying to store a copy of the data in an `AlAsset` into my database as the URL of an image retrieved from my photo library. To do this, I'd like to convert it into an `NSString`, but I'm not sure how.

My intent is to later pull the URL from the database, and load the `AlAsset` or `NSString` path, then use it to load a `UIImage`. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"path : %@", [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL]);
```

And refer my this answer for how to get that image back using this URL:[name of the picked image xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13512260/1548523)

Comment: Is the ALAssetPropertyAssetURL persistent, or can it be reused if that ALAsset is deleted?

Comment: @KevinHarrington, Sorry I could not find a documentation describe this. I guess it will not be reused because the url looks like the hash or something similar. So no two image is exactly same and so no same asset url.